# Java counter is coming up short

Tags: java, arrays, methods, counter, increment

My counter is not working properly. The method accepts a car to add into the parking garage array. The parking garage can only hold up to 10 cars, but when I run my program its only allowing up to 5 cars, even though I have 10 set as the SIZE of the array.

```
    //instance variables.

private Car automobiles[];  //Array List of Cars
private int counter = 0;   //counter to keep track of cars in garage.
private Car toyota;    // car object
private static final int SIZE = 10;


    public String arrive(Car next)
  {

    toyota = next;
    if (counter < SIZE) // checks to make sure the garage is not full 
      {

        automobiles[counter] = toyota;  //parks new car into garage
        counter++;

        return "" + toyota.getlicenseNumber() + " has been parked.\n";

      }

    else // else statement if garage is full
      {
        return "Sorry, " + toyota.getlicenseNumber()
                + " cannot be parked. The Parking lot is Full!!";
      }

  }
```

HERE IS MY OUTPUT

```
    JAV001 has been parked.

    JAV002 has been parked.

    JAV003 has been parked.

    JAV004 has been parked.

    JAV005 has been parked.

    Sorry, JAV006 cannot be parked. The Parking lot is Full!!
    Sorry, JAV007 cannot be parked. The Parking lot is Full!!
    Sorry, JAV008 cannot be parked. The Parking lot is Full!!
    Sorry, JAV009 cannot be parked. The Parking lot is Full!!
    Sorry, JAV0010 cannot be parked. The Parking lot is Full!!
```

Comment: Is it threaded?  Are cars being removed?  Can you provide a fully runnable example that demonstrates your problem?

Comment: Looks like the part of your code that's broken isn't included. Where are you looping through the data? This only runs once and would not produce that output.

Comment: Check all references/uses of the counter variable because the code above looks okay.  Maybe counter is being incremented elsewhere?

Comment: Hey thanks so much for all of the responses, it was actually an issue with my main method, I was calling this arrive method twice.  One to print out the results to the screen and again to print the results to a text file and this was causing the counter to increment. :)

Answer (score 2):

```
private static final int SIZE = 10;
```

You have made the `SIZE` as `static/Class variable` and

```
private int counter = 0;
```

`counter` as `instance variable`.

So even if you want maximum 10 cars in one garage instance due to your declaration of SIZE as static you can have maximum of 10 cars in all your garage instances. So if your previous instances have 5 cars it will allow only 5 more. You may want to make SIZE as an instance variable.

```
private final int SIZE = 10;
```

Comment: I don't see how this makes any difference. He does nothing with the value of SIZE shy of use it in place of typing a 10. Instance or class variable changes nothing from the looks of it.

Comment: Since he as mentioned instance variables as comments in the code I am assuming code belongs to `Garage class`. Next SIZE is defined as `static` and `arrive()` is instance method in which OP is comparing counter with SIZE. So he can only have 10 cars irrespective of garage instances. So if there were garage instances earlier where cars have already arrived them current instances can have maximum of `SIZE-thatNumber` cars.

Comment: I still don't see how ` if (counter < SIZE)` changes. If he puts 8 cars in Garage1 and creates a second garage, Garage2 it's going to hit that if statement... and 10 isn't going to be any different for Garage2. Garage2 is going to have a new instance counter of 0 and a Class variable SIZE of 10. so `if(0 < 10)` with no connection to the number of cars in the other garage.

What you are saying would make sense if counter were the class variable.

Comment: I get your point. Or if he was decrementing SIZE but even that is not possible as he has declared it as final.